# c# I cannot print a message from a loop

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I am trying to make a simple program that takes in 2 integers: a number and a width. I want it to print a triangle with that width using that number. Should I use a double for loop instead if not can it be done my way?

```
class Program
    {
        public static int readInt()
        {
            int result;
            string resultString = Console.ReadLine();
            result = int.Parse(resultString);
            return result;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int number, width;

            Console.WriteLine("Enter a number: ");
            number = readInt();

            Console.WriteLine("Enter a width: ");
            width = readInt();

            do {
                for (int i = width; i < 0; i--)
                {
                    Console.Write(number);
                    width--;
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
            } while (width < 0);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Output:
number:7
width:4

```
7777
777
77
7
```

Comment: First, since widths are positive values, this line `for (int i = width; i < 0; i--)` will do nothing and even if it did, then the enclosed `width--;` would cause width to go to zero. Second, `while (width < 0)` would always "fail" since widths are always greater than zero. You need to rethink your code from scratch.

Comment: What do you mean with _print a triangle_?

Comment: Can you give us an idea of what the output should look like?  Also, use the debugger to follow what your program is doing and inspect the values of the variables along the way.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, this version will print a rectangle centered

```
int space = 0;
do
{
    // Prints initial spaces
    for(int x = 0; x < space; x++)
        Console.Write("-");

    // Print the number for the current value of width        
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
        Console.Write(number);

    // Print final spaces - 
    // Not really needed 
    for (int x = 0; x < space; x++)
        Console.Write("-");

    // Start the new line
    Console.WriteLine();

    //Decrease width by one space for each end (2)
    width-=2;

    // Increment the spaces to print before and after
    space++;
} while (width > 0);
```

A part from the logic completely rewritten note that Console.WriteLine appends a newline, so you need to use Console.Write